# Scheme Language: +: contract violation, expected: number?

Tags: scheme, racket

My assignment looks like this:
Suppose you are writing a Scheme program for a grocery store that will calculate the total price of a customer’s items, represented as a list.  Your partner suggests writing a series of Scheme forms like (define item price) then recursively going through the list using those defines to calculate the sum.
I wrote the **code**, but when I call the function, I get an error.

```
#lang scheme
(define milk 2.99)
(define chicken 7.99)
(define carrots 1.99)
(define add-cart
  (lambda(x)
    (if (empty? x) 0
        (+ (car x) (add-cart (cdr x))))))
(add-cart '(milk chicken carrots))
```

**Error:**

```
+: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: carrots
```

I am still new too scheme just got introduced to it last week, but it is really frustrating. What am I doing wrong? Maybe you have some advice? I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: You're passing the symbol `milk` to the function, not the value of the variable `milk`.

Comment: Change `'(milk chicken carrots)` to `(list milk chicken carrots)`